# Save Excel values while parsing in Python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

I want to take an excel file, which contains different cell types like dates, currency ETC and parse it with Python including the cell types.

I have tried using `Pandas`, but when I open it with Python using `pd.read_excel`, all of these cell types are disappearing.

For Example - a cell containing `'50 USD'` (Cell containing currency type) will be shown as `'50'`.

Is there a method in Python that is able to read these cells with their cell types saved?

Thanks

Comment: have u had a look at [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html). it could require a bit of tinkering, but possible

Comment: What would be the python `dtype` for currency? Imo there is non such datatype. However you can parse dates

Comment: 1. I have checked, and openpyxl Does not save currency, but does save dates (but I think pandas is already doing it).

Comment: 2. I don't know what is the dtype because I can't catch it until now. The optimal case for me is that the cell values and type will be taken as one string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confusing cell values and cell formatting. For example, with 50 USD, Excel stores the numeric value and then applies a currency format for display. So it is correct to read it into pandas as an integer if you want to sum, average, or otherwise analyze that column.

Dates should be automatically parsed and, if they aren't, `read_excel` has a `parse_dates` parameter that allows you to do so.

Now, depending on how you want to output the data after you've manipulated it in pandas, you could have a function that outputs a new dataframe that converts all values to string and applies formats to different columns. Or, if you are working in a notebook, you can use the pandas styling API. You could also write the file back to excel with pandas and then apply styles programatically with openpyxl.

Comment: I know it is not an intergrated part of the cell itself, but if I do want so save it, what are my options? because I did found linux methods that saves these types as strings when converting into a csv file, but in Python I did not find any.